# Is GPS and GPRS disabled with partial lock in sleep mode?

Tags: android, gps, sleep, gprs

I can't find info. Are GPS and GPRS (mobile data) automatically disabled by Android system with partial lock in sleep mode when phone screen is off?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html (see remark after the table describing the flags): If you hold a partial wake lock the CPU will remain on, thus you are able to receive GPS updates. It works, I am using this feature in a GPS flight logging app.